# How can I extend the root storage with a SD card?

Tags: filesystems, mount, storage, sd-card

I am working on a device that runs Ubuntu. It has small storage capacity, this is the output of the `df -h` command:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mmcblk0p1   28G   25G  1,3G  96% /
none            3,5G     0  3,5G   0% /dev
tmpfs           3,9G   40K  3,9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           3,9G   30M  3,9G   1% /run
tmpfs           5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           3,9G     0  3,9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0      100M  100M     0 100% /snap/cmake/925
/dev/loop1       29M   29M     0 100% /snap/snapd/12886
/dev/loop2       49M   49M     0 100% /snap/core18/2127
tmpfs           786M   12K  786M   1% /run/user/120
tmpfs           786M  140K  785M   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/mmcblk2p1   58G   32K   58G   1% /media/nvidia/SDcard
```

I plugged in a sd card of 64 GB:

```
/dev/mmcblk2p1   58G   32K   58G   1% /media/nvidia/SDcard
```

My purpose is to extend the root storage :

```
/dev/mmcblk0p1   28G   25G  1,3G  96% /
```

Is it possible? Can I mount my sd card on root / ? How can I do it? Sorry if my question is bad, I am begginer in UNIX system and I preffered first to ask before to do something bad.

Comment: Unless you set up LVM you can not extend your root partition across multiple devices/partitions.

Comment: You can change the whole disk if you want. But....
cd / ; du -hd 1 
output?

Answer (score 1):

You could extend your root partition over multiple devices with LVM, but I would not recommend it. If your main device is an eMMC, the SDcard is probably less reliable and quite slow in comparison.

The typical way to deal with that situation is to identify the directory where you need more space, move it to the SDcard and mount it to the according directory.

For example, you have a big application on `/opt`, you can

```
mkdir /tmp/mnt
sudo mount /dev/mmcblk2p1 /tmp/mnt
sudo mv /opt/* /tmp/mnt
```

and later add something like

```
/dev/mmcblk2p1    /opt    ext4   rw    1    1
```

to your `/etc/fstab` to automount it on boot. You can do this with other directories, too, but I recommend to keep everything critical on the root partition, so the system can boot and be maintained without the SDcard.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can be done for current linux technology because linux still recognizes the permanent storage place in the device