# How to free memory in root file system

Tags: arch-linux, filesystems, root-filesystem

I have a lap top that has had Arch Linux installed for approximately two years.  Yesterday, when conducting a daily update via the command `sudo pacman -Syu` I recieved the warning `the volume Filesystem root has only 1.0GB disk space`.  I ran the commands `df -h` and `df -i` and received the following outputs.

```
$ df -h         
Filesystem                     Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
dev                            7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /dev
run                            7.7G  2.1M  7.7G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/volgroup0-lv_root   30G   27G  1.4G  96% /
tmpfs                          7.7G   41M  7.7G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                          7.7G  4.3M  7.7G   1% /tmp
/dev/nvme0n1p2                 459M  157M  273M  37% /boot
/dev/mapper/volgroup0-lv_home  908G   63G  799G   8% /home
tmpfs                          1.6G  104K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000

$ df -i
Filesystem                       Inodes   IUsed     IFree IUse% Mounted on
dev                             2004803     790   2004013    1% /dev
run                             2010868    1373   2009495    1% /run
/dev/mapper/volgroup0-lv_root   1966080  433229   1532851   23% /
tmpfs                           2010868     105   2010763    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                           1048576      58   1048518    1% /tmp
/dev/nvme0n1p2                   128016     379    127637    1% /boot
/dev/mapper/volgroup0-lv_home  60481536  340313  60141223    1% /home
tmpfs                            402173     148    402025    1% /run/user/1000
```

I tried to mount `volgroup0-lv_root` to see what was taking so much memory, but it appears that it does not have access to several folders.  How should I go about freeing memory in the root filesystem or is their a way to resize it, since I have so much available memory in lv_home?  It would appear that this is being caused by daily updates, is their something related to the updates that may be causing this, and if so is their a pacman command to free get rid of residuals like zip files, etc., if that is what is causing this?

Comment: FYI, "memory" refers to RAM, not to disk or other storage space  (except when marketers are trying to lie to consumers about how much "memory" is available in a PC or laptop or phone or whatever).

Comment: Your best options are to either 1. backup your data & config files and rebuild your system so that there is only one partition or LV for both / and /home, or 2. move and symlink some directories from / to /home.  I recommend replicating the directory structure from / underneath /home for any dirs you move.  e.g. to move /usr/share/doc/ from / to /home: `mkdir -p /home/usr/share ; mv /usr/share/doc /home/usr/share; ln -s /home/usr/share/doc /usr/share`.   Selected sub-directories under /var may also be good candidates for move-and-symlink. Don't move lib or bin directories (or be very careful).

Comment: Another option would be to allocate more disk space (say, another 70GB) to `lv-root`.  If there's no free space in `volgroup0`, you'll have to take some from `lv-home` so you can add it to `lv-root`.  This will involve shrinking the lv-home filesystem, then the LV, then adding the newly freed space to lv-root and growing the filesystem.  It isn't exactly "hard" to do but does require planning and attention to detail and caution (e.g. double-checking & triple-checking every command before you hit enter to make sure you aren't about to make a mistake).

Comment: [gparted](https://gparted.org/) can make this easier.   I don't have time to write an actual answer describing how to do any of this but if anyone (including you, Jon) wants to use some or even all of my comments to write an answer then feel free to do so.

Comment: Different situation, but the same problem: [How can I extend the root storage with a SD card?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/667981/how-can-i-extend-the-root-storage-with-a-sd-card)

Comment: And @cas, your definition of »memory« is fine, but not universally valid. People are talking about »non-volatile memory«, too. Do you remember, what the M in CD-ROM stands for? If you remember, it's probably stored in your brain's non-volatile memory. (-; It's nice to use precise terms for what you express, but also nice to be tolerant about less precise terms used by others.

Comment: I was not offended by the language used by cas, and actually appreciate the input.  I will explore these options over the weekend and report back.  Thank you!

Comment: I just re-posted this question with a possible process at the link below.  Please let me know if any of you believe this process to be incorrect.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/755777/what-is-the-correct-process-to-resize-logical-volumes-on-arch-linux