# What is the correct process to resize logical volumes on Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, memory

I use an Arch Linux distribution on my lap top and a few days ago I ran an update with the command `sudo pacman -Syu`.  The update was executed succesfully; however, I received the following error,

```
the volume Filesystem root has only 1.0GB disk space
```

I ran the command `df -h` and I received this output.

```
Filesystem                     Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
dev                            7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /dev
run                            7.7G  2.1M  7.7G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/volgroup0-lv_root   30G   27G  1.4G  96% /
tmpfs                          7.7G   41M  7.7G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                          7.7G  4.3M  7.7G   1% /tmp
/dev/nvme0n1p2                 459M  157M  273M  37% /boot
/dev/mapper/volgroup0-lv_home  908G   63G  799G   8% /home
tmpfs                          1.6G  104K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000
```

I also ran `df -i` and received this output.

```
Filesystem                       Inodes   IUsed     IFree IUse% Mounted on
dev                             2004803     790   2004013    1% /dev
run                             2010868    1373   2009495    1% /run
/dev/mapper/volgroup0-lv_root   1966080  433229   1532851   23% /
tmpfs                           2010868     105   2010763    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                           1048576      58   1048518    1% /tmp
/dev/nvme0n1p2                   128016     379    127637    1% /boot
/dev/mapper/volgroup0-lv_home  60481536  340313  60141223    1% /home
tmpfs                            402173     148    402025    1% /run/user/1000
```

I had considered just re-installing everything and giving the `root` directory 100GB of space instead of 30GB; however, the process of reinstalling everything will take days.  Instead I think I may be better off re-allocating memory from the `home` volume to the `root` volume.  I have to admit that I do not have much experience doing re-allocating memory.  Before I execute the commands I believe to be correct, wanted to bounce the process as best i know it, off an audience that may no better than I how to do this.  I will list my process below, and please tell me if you think it is correct, or where it is flawed.

```
1. Backup all data
2. Flash a thumb drive with the most current version of Arch Linux
3. Boot from the thumb drive in live mode
4. Unmount volumes
    umount /dev/mapper/volgroup0-lv_home
    umount /dev/mapper/volgroup0-lv_root
5. Check for filesystem errors
    e2fsck -f /dev/mapper/volgroup0-lv_home
    e2fsck -f /dev/mapper/volgroup0-lv_root
6. Shrink the home Filesystem from 799 to 700 GB 
    resize2fs /dev/mapper/volgroup0-lv_home 700G
7. Reduce the lb_home logical volume
    lvreduce -L 700G /dev/mapper/volgroup0-lv_home
8. Extend the lv_root logical volume
    lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/volgroup0-lv_root
9. Extend the / filesystem
    resize2fs /dev/mapper/volgroup0-lv_root
10. Re-mount volumes
    mount /dev/mapper/volgroup0-lv_home /home
    mount /dev/mapper/volgroup0-lv_root /
11. Verify file systems
    df -h
```

Comment: If you're considering a reinstall, then you need to ask yourself why you need/want to use LVM. For single-user systems, it seems like it's more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: This isn't an Arch Linux thing but an LVM thing. I doubt the default Arch installer uses LVM (though I don't know that for sure) so I assume it's a thing you set up yourself? Or does it really use LVM by default?

Comment: @user253751 I set this up myself, and Arch does not have an installer, the installation process is manual.

Comment: @ajgringo619 I will admit that to an extent I took advice from more knowledgeable people when i set my installation up, but many people told me logical volumes would be a better choice if I needed to resize memory, which I think is the very situation I am in.  Although to be fair, I am not adding memory, but re-allocating it.

Comment: Before I take the plunge, do any of you think the instructions I wrote above are incorrect?

Comment: You should change the question so that it's about LVM instead of about Arch Linux.

Comment: I don't think it is about Arch Linux, it is about LVM, I am just stating that it is on Arch Linux in case that might draw a different answer than it would if it were on Fedora, Ubuntu, etc, because I am not sure if it would or not.  Regardless, do you have an answer to the question?

Comment: this look good, providing `/home` is downsizable (e.g. not xfs), can you provide revelanf line of `/etc/fstab` ?

Comment: @Archemar Sure, the output of `cat /etc/fstab` looks like this

`UUID=53336e06-55d5-462e-9a5a-b17c8bda341f /          ext4       rw,relatime 0 1

# /dev/nvme0n1p2
UUID=9779e6c1-2144-42c2-9625-08540d8f5cd2 /boot      ext4       rw,relatime 0 2

# /dev/mapper/volgroup0-lv_home
UUID=1c422bce-a527-437d-addb-ba5421d57a29 /home      ext4       rw,relatime 0 2`

Does this have to be run in live mode, or can I run this when booted in normal mode?