# Logical volumes missing in live mode

Tags: partition, lvm

I am running Arch Linux (Linux 6.4.12-arch-1-1) on a Dell Lap top and have recently discovered that I am running out of space on one of my logical volumes i.e `/dev/mapper/volgroup0-lv_root`.  I am considering the process of moving memory allocations from my other logical volume `/dev/mapper/volgroup0-lv_home` to the `lv_root` volume.  IN order to do this I flashed the most recent Arch Linux iso to a thumb drive and have booted into live mode.  However, once I am in live mode, I run `modprobe dm_mod` and `vgscan` as well as `vgchange -ay` to activate all logical volumes.  I then type `vgdisplay` and `lvdisplay` to show the existing logical volumes and nothing is shown.  I know the volumes exist because I can see them when booted normally using the `lvdisplay` command. How do I get them to be active and displayed when in live mode?

Comment: Did you mount the harddisk into the live system? Resizing LVM partitions does not necessarily require you to be in a live system.

Comment: There is no need to boot into a live USB to work with logical volumes. You can do what you are trying to do in the regular state of the OS.

Comment: 1) have you tried `pvscan` ? 2) beware before downsizing `lv_home`, be sure you know how to shrink a filesystem

Comment: @NasirRiley  What is the process for doing this in a normal boot mode.  I made this post a few weeks ago regarding how I intended to do this in the live mode.  Can I follow the same process.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/755777/what-is-the-correct-process-to-resize-logical-volumes-on-arch-linux

Comment: @Archemar I have tried pvscan and it is not working.  I agree with your concerns on downsizing lv_home.  I posted a process last week hoping someone could critique it.  If you could look at it and provide comments before I execute it, I would appreciate it.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/755777/what-is-the-correct-process-to-resize-logical-volumes-on-arch-linux